# How do I change Shared System Memory for GPU in Windows 11 without BIOS

Tags: memory, graphics-card, bios, gpu, vram

I have an [Acer Laptop](https://www.startech.com.bd/acer-aspire-3-a315-23-amd-ryzen-3-fhd-laptop) with following Graphics Configurations :
[Generic PNP Monitor and AMD Graphics Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZOh6.png).

I had 4GB RAM installed and very recently have installed another 4GB. But the GPU is allocating 3GB **shared system memory** for itself. I want to reduce it to 1GB. I don't need so much VRAM as I don't do stuffs that requires GPU heavily, e.g. playing games.

I did some searching on YouTube and Google about this. Most answers are about changing in BIOS, which my laptop doesn't support(not available in BIOS options). But, there were other answers changing by *RegEdit* which is only for *Dedicated Video Memory* which I have enough. I want to reduce memory consumption by GPU from my RAM.

In summary, I am searching for an answer of reducing shared system memory in Windows 11 using Registry Editor and without BIOS, as I don't have the option in my laptop.

Comment: It's either an option in the firmware (UEFI, you don't have BIOS) or it isn't.

Comment: No, it isn't an option in the BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: For those thinking it is a BIOS-thing: No, it isn't. The integrated GPU gets around 64-128MB for booting tasks, then it is up to the OS to see how much of the RAM it reserves for the GPU. This is also shared with additional dedicated GPUs which might be installed.

If you boot the same machine into Kubuntu, it will have close to the full amount of RAM available for applications to use, no problems there. Microsoft's view on this is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Because most integrated graphics solutions automatically adjust to use the amount of system RAM they need, for integrated graphics the
*Dedicated Video Memory* value is completely fictitious.
The system reports a dummy value simply so games see something when
they check how much VRAM you have.

I don't know how you found 3GB as the size of the shared system
memory, but this number is totally bogus.
The video memory can only get up to 50% of the system RAM, and
even that may be further limited by hardware considerations.

The amount VRAM your system reports can be modified in the registry.
This doesn't actually change your VRAM - it just modifies that
dummy value.
You would typically increase it if a game refuses to start because
you "don't have enough VRAM".

This registry item is found at
`HKEY LOCAL MACHINE/Intel/GMM` as a DWORD called `DedicatedSegmentSize`,
in units of megabyte.

It's possible that this value used to do some actual RAM allocation
in older Windows systems (it's certainly documented as such),
but in Windows 10 & 11 it's just cosmetics.

Comment: You can see in the picture added on the first line(forgot to crop :D). It says 3GB shared system memory. Okay. How can I see how much system memory the GPU is really consuming? Because I don't feel much improvement after installing the extra 4GB, as expectation.

Comment: See https://levvvel.com/how-to-check-vram-usage/#:~:text=Once%20there%2C%20look%20for%20the,usage%20is%20via%20MSI%20Afterburner